# manipulating DateTime on a field

Tags: datetime, developer

I have been receiving datetime **eventtime** in Local time zone say(2020-10-04T23:02:20).I have stored **starttime** as 22:00 and **endtime** as 5:00(which denotes 5 AM) in a custom setting. I need to subtract event time(23) from endtime(5) and populate a field on an object with dateTime value and status queued.

**What I am trying to achieve:**

I have been trying to set up a curfew time for not sending messages in Service Cloud. I receive events from external system with localtime in the payload. If the localtime is between 22:00-5:00,I don't want to send the SMSes out during that time window but I need to store those messages to send them out when it is morning(after 5 AM)in the localtimezone.

**My Approach**

I have stored the starttime and endTime in custom metadata as 22:00-05:00.I have created an object to store those messages and a specific Datetime field called **scheduletime**.I want to populate scheduletime as : currentTime + (difference between endTime and EventTime). So If an event comes  with eventTime 2020-10-04T23:02:20 local time Newyork, I will store this message and populate the field scheduletime as Currentdatetime (say 15:00)+(5 AM-23 PM) which should be 2020-10-04 21:00(meaning after 6 hours this message should be processed when it will be morning in Newyork) so when my batch job runs at 21:00 my time, it will query all the messages with field status as queued and scheduletime as its runningtime.

I just need help with populating scheduleTime on my object.let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: Can you tell from where do you get the datetime? Is it a service? Also, for the incoming eventtime is there a specific local timezone or it can any timezone and how you make out that which timezone is the time in with that format

Comment: @ manjit5190 yes we do get the EventTime from a Service.And for the incoming EventTime,it can be any local timezone.I do not need to make out the timezone of the location. But whatever is sent to us say 22:00, 23:00, 10:00, I would know, if I need to send the message now or store the messages. if it is between 22:00-5:00, I would know, I don't need to send the message.Now I would have to find the morning time when i can reprocess those messages , which I think can achieve from the logic described(by setting the scheduletime) in the post. This is the approach i am thinking.